# How to map only values of HashMap - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to map only the values of a map to database.
In the example below, in class `Holder`, there's a map of ID, Entity, being the ID a `BigInteger` and the entity `Item`. 
I'm doing this because I want fast search and hashmap K,V is good for that.
But, now, the mapping is weird.

The JoinTable `holder_items` now has 3 columns, `holder_id`. `item_id` and `item_KEY`.
Can I have only `older_id` and `item_Id`?

Basically, mapping only `items.values()` to the current Holder.

```
@Entity
public class Holder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "holder_items",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "holder_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    )
    private Map<BigInteger, Item> items = new HashMap<>();
    //(...)
}

@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BIGINT")
    private BigInteger id;
    //(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this mapping without the third table if it is not necessary ofc. Example:

```java
@Entity
public class Holder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @MapKey(name = "id")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="holder")
    private Map<BigInteger, Item> items = new HashMap<>();
```

```java
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BIGINT")
    private BigInteger id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Holder holder;
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary that the ``Item`` also has a reference to the Owner when using ``OneToMany``?

Comment: But your solution on the ``Holder`` seems to work without the "mappedBy"!
I'll test to see if it's really ok.

Comment: @DavidFrickert You can do this relation to be unidirectional

Comment: Thanks for the help! Also posted answer to how I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with help of [@Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8872018/anthony)

```
@Entity
public class Holder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @MapKey(name = "id")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "holder_items",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "holder_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    )
    private Map<BigInteger, Item> items = new HashMap<>();
```

-

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BIGINT")
    private BigInteger id;
}
```

Results in table `holder_items` with `holder_id` and `item_id`, as desired!